# How do I tell proguard to not do anything except some stripping

Tags: proguard

I'm using progurad to get rid of some logging:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static int d(...);
    public static int v(...);
}
```

I don't want anything else to happen to any classes. In particular I don't want any obfuscation, since this is a library. The clients of the library will apply obfuscation themselfs.

Is there a way to tell proguard to do "nothing" except the -assumenosideeffects rule please?

Answer (score 0):

This option is applied in the optimization step, so you could disable shrinking and obfuscation. You still need to provide -keep options, e.g. ProGuard manual > Examples > A typical library.